# How to get popups forms in rails 3.2.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get form dialogs popups in a rails application. In the application there is a form to create a resource called Movement this resorce must have associate another resource called Concept for this exists a list box to select one but I want to have a button  when is clicked open a dialog form to create a new concept. The application is running with rails 3.2.6 and are installed jquery-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ujs gems. In the site https://github.com/ramblex/modal-form I found an example but I'm no able this example works. There are 3 main codes and they are: create.js.erb(view), modalform.js, _form.html.erb I can't run this example due rake's version but I took the example and I tried to implement in my application.

create.js.erb

```
    <%-if @article.errors.any? %>
         console.log('Error');
         $('#dialog-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %>');
        <%- else %>
         console.log('Created');
         $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
        $('#dialog-form').remove();
       $('table').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(@article)) %>');
    <%- end %>
```

modalform.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#create_article').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var dialog_form = $('<div id="dialog-form">Loading form...</div>').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
        width: 520,
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
            return $(this).load(url + ' #content');
        },
        close: function() {
            $('#dialog-form').remove();
        }
    });
    dialog_form.dialog('open');
    e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

I didn't have a resorce Article then I created a scaffold for this only too see if the example works but it wasn't. Te scaffold was Article title:string after the that I changed the file new.html.erb in the articles views and replace the code for

new.js.erb

```
<%-if @article.errors.any? %>
    console.log('Error');
    $('#dialog-form').html('<%= escape_javascript render 'form'%>');
<%-else %>
    console.log('Created');
    $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
    $('#dialog-form').remove();
    $('table').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(@article)) %>');
<%-end %>
```

Then in the view index.html.erb of the article views change the link to new article for the line

```
<%= link_to 'New Article', new_article_path, :id => "create_article"%>
```

I took the Javascript code and put it in vendor/assets/javascripts and add the line

```
//=require modalform
```

in application.js in app/assets/javascripts.

With all this done I run the application go to articles clic on the New Article link and the only thing that apperars was the elment dialog-for without the form's elements by the way the form is a form_for with :remote => true I change for form_tag and still not working

http://i46.tinypic.com/11sp4j5.png

To try found what is happening in the application I'm playing with code and to get help I use firebug of firefox, first in the console an error was showed:template missing, then I change the new.js.erb an only leaving the line

```
$('#dialog-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %>');
```

Check again and in the response of the console this was the output

```
    $('#dialog-form').html('<form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/articles\"    class=\"new_article\" id=\"new_article\" method=\"post\">
<div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;  display:inline\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" />
<input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"Vw6+xyfR/hnJutu/8Q2yLIqkau/s2xebEygKGZF07O8=\" />
<\/div>\n\n  <div class=\"field\">\n    <label for=\"article_title\">Title<\/label><br />\n    
<input id=\"article_title\" name=\"article[title]\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" />\n  <\/div>\n  <div class=\"actions\">\n   
<input    name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Create Article\" />\n  <\/div>\n<\/form>');
```

I cut the code an edit the html code and putit between the form-dialog div and the result was a form with plenty of characters / \n etc.

Then I thank this was the problem and I play with the code until I found deleting scape_javascript in the new.js.erb solve the extra characters but still no loading the form into the form-dialog div

```
$('#dialog-form').html('<%= render 'form'%>');
```

Check again the response and this was the response

```
$('#dialog-form').html('<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/articles" class="new_article" id="new_article" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Vw8+xyfR/hnJutu/8Q2yNIqvau/x2xebPqgKGZF0728=" /></div>

 <div class="field">
   <label for="article_title">Title</label><br />
   <input id="article_title" name="article[title]" size="30" type="text" />
   </div>
  <div class="actions">
   <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Article" />
 </div>
</form>');
```

Again I cut this output into the form-dialog div in the html code output and obtain a correct form. 
Well I tried to save an article and it works but remember that I put manually the html code de response in a manually way.

But the problem continue (the form is not loading into the form-dialog div)for itself

The code for the partial _form in the articles wiew is

```
<%= form_for(@article)  do |f|  %>
    <% if @article.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article     from being saved:</h2>

         <ul>
           <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
             <li><%= msg %></li>
           <% end %>
          </ul>
      </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

And I think is important to show you the code in the ArticlesController especially in the action new.

```
# GET /articles/new
# GET /articles/new.json
def new
    @article = Article.new

    respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    #format.html # new.js.erb
    #format.json { render json: @article }
end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What, you think it was? a simple space in

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#create_article').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var dialog_form = $('<div id="dialog-form">Loading form...</div>').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 520,
    modal: true,
    open: function() {
    return $(this).load(url + ' #content');
   },
   close: function() {
    $('#dialog-form').remove();
   }
 });
 dialog_form.dialog('open');
 e.preventDefault();
 });
 });
```

Exactly in the line

```
return $(this).load(url + ' #content');
```

It must be

```
return $(this).load(url + '#content');
```

Well using the code of Alex Duller and reiterating that my application is running on version 3.2.8

These are the final codes

new.html.erb (myaplication/app/views/articles)

```
 <%= render 'form' %>
```

Note that was eliminated several lines and it reduced only to one.

articles_controller.erb (myaplication/app/controllers)

```
def new
  @article = Article.new

  respond_to do |format|   
   format.js
  end
end
```

Finally the title of this question initially was How to reach that the new.js.erb loads into a popup windw? But it changes to How to get popups forms in rails 3.2.6